# How to convert a pdf into word file

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have a pdf file which is in hindi, I need to convert it in word file. I have tried some online tools and desktop application that convert to convert to word successfully but after conversion I can't read that file. The converted file is full of unreadable characters. It looks like the conversion tool don't support pdf which are in hindi.

So, is there any way to deal this?thanks

Comment: Please mention exactly which online tools and applications you've tried.

Comment: http://www.pdftoword.com/ I used this sites online tool.

Answer (score 2):

Try this tool, it's free: http://unipdf.com/

> Supported PDF File Languages UniPDF supports almost all of the major
>   languages including English, Spanish, Portuguese, German, French,
>   Italian, Polish, Russian, Chinese, Chinese Traditional, Korean,
>   Japanese, Hindi, Arabic,Turkish etc.

Comment: It seems like that file is password protected because in the status field it says.... Need Password.

Comment: Try to use the solution of MartialE: http://superuser.com/a/605532/192966

Comment: It does not support Hindi :(

Answer (score 2):

If the PDF is lock with password or restrictions use:

http://www.pdfunlock.com/

> Remove passwords and restrictions from secured PDF files!

After this try the solution of @duDe

https://superuser.com/a/605519/227987

Comment: There are some problems, when I tried to remove restriction by http://pdfunlock.com it said that no restriction on file, property filed also does not show any restriction, but when I am trying to convert using @duDe solution it says need passwrod. However that application successfully converts other pdf files.

Answer (score 1):

Office 2013 will do that for you just by opening it in word.